# examples are not appearing in the feature object and scenario object of pytest-bdd

Tags: pytest, bdd, pytest-xdist, pytest-bdd

I am trying to fetch the scenario.examples or feature.examples from the conftest.py file. But When I am using these objects it fetches the feature details but examples object is not appearing. Understanding is that it should provide the examples object inside it no matter if the examples are avialable or not in the feature file.

Can someone help to understand the issue?

I tried to look if any particular supported plugin is needed or not, I am trying to fetch the examples.example information from pytest_bdd_before_scenario on conftest.py